# How do I call the service that is going to be on the server on the client in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, protocol-buffers, grpc, grpc-c#

**I get this exception when I try to connect to the grpc service on the server on the client. What is the correct solution to call the server service on the client? Please help me about the mistake I made in the sample code. When I give the local address in the grpc channel, the process works fine for me and I can see the output, but when I want to call the grpc service that is on the server with I get an error. Is it necessary to write more configurations to call the service ..??**

```
syntax = "proto3";

option csharp_namespace = "GrpcServiceSample";

package greet;

// The greeting service definition.
service Greeter {
  // Sends a greeting
  rpc SayHello (HelloRequest) returns (HelloReply);
}

// The request message containing the user's name.
message HelloRequest {
  string name = 1;
}

// The response message containing the greetings.
message HelloReply {
  string message = 1;
}
```

```
using ClientSample.Service;
using grpcSample;
using Microsoft.OpenApi.Models;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddControllers();
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();

builder.Services.AddGrpcClient<Greeter.GreeterClient>();

builder.Services.AddCors(options => {
    options.AddPolicy("cors", policy => {
        policy.AllowAnyMethod()
        .AllowAnyHeader()
        .AllowAnyOrigin()
        .WithExposedHeaders("Grpc-Status", "Grpc-Message", "Grpc-Encoding", "Grpc-Accept-Encoding");
    });
});
builder.Services.AddGrpc().AddJsonTranscoding();
builder.Services.AddGrpcSwagger();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
{
    c.SwaggerDoc("v1",
        new OpenApiInfo { Title = "gRPC transcoding", Version = "v1" });
});

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment() || app.Environment.IsProduction())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseRouting();
app.UseGrpcWeb(new GrpcWebOptions { DefaultEnabled = true });
app.UseCors();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

```
using Grpc.Core;
using Grpc.Net.Client;
using grpcSample;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace ClientSample.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class GrpcController : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
        {
            try
            {
                AppContext.SetSwitch(
           "System.Net.Http.SocketsHttpHandler.Http2UnencryptedSupport", true);

                var httpHandler = new HttpClientHandler()
                {
                    ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = HttpClientHandler.DangerousAcceptAnyServerCertificateValidator

                };
                var channel = GrpcChannel.ForAddress("https://100.100.22.19:443/grpcSample/" , new GrpcChannelOptions
                {
                    HttpHandler = httpHandler
                });
                var client = new Greeter.GreeterClient(channel);

                var response = await client.SayHelloAsync(new HelloRequest { Name = ".NET 7.0" });
                return Ok(response);
            }
            catch (RpcException ex)
            {
                throw ex.InnerException;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**The exception that the compiler shows me after running the code:**

```
Grpc.Core.RpcException: Status(StatusCode="Unimplemented", Detail="Service is unimplemented.")
```

Comment: Every Server is different and code that runs on one Server may not run on another Server.  The error indicates that "https://100.100.22.19:444/grpcSample" is not implemented.    It could mean that one Machine with IP 100.100.22.19 there is no Service running on Port 444, or the service is running but there is not route for grpcSample.